# Как реализовать уменьшение и увеличение окна с последующим увеличением или уменьшением содержимого в нем, PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Хочу реализовать с своей программе такую вещь, чтобы окно можно было увеличить или уменьшить, но при этом содержимое окна (кнопки, текст и т.д.) тоже меняли свой размер. Как это можно сделать?

И хотелось бы добавить вертикальные и горизонтальные скроллбары, чтобы листать содержимое окна, если оно полностью не влазит.

Код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(732, 570)
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 421, 81))
        self.label_2.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label_2.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label_2.setOpenExternalLinks(False)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.AnswerEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 50, 101, 16))
        self.AnswerEdit.setObjectName("AnswerEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 401, 51))
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 110, 101, 16))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 170, 411, 61))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.AnswerBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 190, 121, 22))
        self.AnswerBox.setStyleSheet("")
        self.AnswerBox.setObjectName("AnswerBox")
        self.AnswerBox.addItem("")
        self.AnswerBox.addItem("")
        self.AnswerBox.addItem("")
        self.AnswerBox.addItem("")
        self.CheckButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 60, 121, 31))
        self.CheckButton.setObjectName("CheckButton")
        self.comboBox_1_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_1_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 260, 111, 22))
        self.comboBox_1_1.setObjectName("comboBox_1_1")
        self.comboBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_1_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 340, 111, 22))
        self.comboBox_1_3.setObjectName("comboBox_1_3")
        self.comboBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_1_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 300, 111, 22))
        self.comboBox_1_2.setObjectName("comboBox_1_2")
        self.comboBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.comboBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 260, 91, 21))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 300, 91, 21))
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 340, 121, 21))
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.AnswerLabel_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerLabel_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 290, 81, 21))
        self.AnswerLabel_2.setObjectName("AnswerLabel_2")
        self.CheckButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 390, 111, 31))
        self.CheckButton_2.setObjectName("CheckButton_2")
        self.AnswerLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 110, 91, 21))
        self.AnswerLabel.setObjectName("AnswerLabel")
        self.WordBox_1_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.WordBox_1_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 260, 111, 22))
        self.WordBox_1_1.setObjectName("WordBox_1_1")
        self.WordBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.DescBox_1_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 260, 111, 22))
        self.DescBox_1_1.setObjectName("DescBox_1_1")
        self.DescBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_1.addItem("")
        self.AnswerLabel_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.AnswerLabel_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(650, 290, 61, 21))
        self.AnswerLabel_3.setObjectName("AnswerLabel_3")
        self.CheckButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 390, 111, 31))
        self.CheckButton_3.setObjectName("CheckButton_3")
        self.WordBox_1_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.WordBox_1_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 290, 111, 22))
        self.WordBox_1_2.setObjectName("WordBox_1_2")
        self.WordBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.WordBox_1_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 320, 111, 22))
        self.WordBox_1_3.setObjectName("WordBox_1_3")
        self.WordBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.WordBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.DescBox_1_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 320, 111, 22))
        self.DescBox_1_3.setObjectName("DescBox_1_3")
        self.DescBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_3.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.DescBox_1_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(530, 290, 111, 22))
        self.DescBox_1_2.setObjectName("DescBox_1_2")
        self.DescBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.DescBox_1_2.addItem("")
        self.CheckButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 190, 81, 23))
        self.CheckButton_4.setObjectName("CheckButton_4")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 732, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "This is a test text. It\'s main                                    is to understand what can i do and how it is possible to create"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "This programm is so                                     (progress) and gives me a lot of abillities and it is awesome"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "There are two versions of this programms and they are really "))
        self.AnswerBox.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Choose a word"))
        self.AnswerBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "difference"))
        self.AnswerBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "different"))
        self.AnswerBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "indifferent"))
        self.CheckButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check"))
        self.comboBox_1_1.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Car"))
        self.comboBox_1_1.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Plane"))
        self.comboBox_1_1.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Boat"))
        self.comboBox_1_3.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Car"))
        self.comboBox_1_3.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Plane"))
        self.comboBox_1_3.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Boat"))
        self.comboBox_1_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Car"))
        self.comboBox_1_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Plane"))
        self.comboBox_1_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Boat"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "moves in the air"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "goes on the road"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "moves on the water"))
        self.AnswerLabel_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.CheckButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check"))
        self.AnswerLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.WordBox_1_1.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Car"))
        self.WordBox_1_1.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Plane"))
        self.WordBox_1_1.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Boat"))
        self.DescBox_1_1.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "moves on the road"))
        self.DescBox_1_1.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "moves on the water"))
        self.DescBox_1_1.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "moves in the air"))
        self.AnswerLabel_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.CheckButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check"))
        self.WordBox_1_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Car"))
        self.WordBox_1_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Plane"))
        self.WordBox_1_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Boat"))
        self.WordBox_1_3.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "Car"))
        self.WordBox_1_3.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Plane"))
        self.WordBox_1_3.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Boat"))
        self.DescBox_1_3.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "moves on the road"))
        self.DescBox_1_3.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "moves on the water"))
        self.DescBox_1_3.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "moves in the air"))
        self.DescBox_1_2.setItemText(0, _translate("MainWindow", "moves on the road"))
        self.DescBox_1_2.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "moves on the water"))
        self.DescBox_1_2.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "moves in the air"))
        self.CheckButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check"))

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.CheckButton.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer1)
        self.CheckButton_2.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer2)

        self.a = " "
        self.b = " "

    def setanswer1(self):
        self.a = self.AnswerEdit.text()
        self.b = self.lineEdit_2.text()

    def checkanswer1(self):
        self.setanswer1()
        if str(self.a) == "aim":
            self.AnswerEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color : green}")
        elif str(self.a) == "":
            pass
        else:
            self.AnswerEdit.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color : red}")

        if str(self.b) == "progressive" :
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color : green}")
        elif str(self.b) == "" :
            pass
        else:
            self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { color : red}")

    def checkanswer2(self):
        if self.comboBox_1_1.currentText() == "Car":
            self.AnswerLabel_2.setText('good job')
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
            self.setStyleSheet(""" 
                QComboBox#comboBox_1_1 {
                    background: red;
                    color: #fff;
                }
                QLabel#AnswerLabel_2 {
                    background: red;
                    color: #fff;
                }
            """)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        else:
            self.AnswerLabel_2.setText("Try again")
            self.setStyleSheet("")                                       # +++



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы реализовали свою форму в `Qt Designer`, поэтому вертикальные и горизонтальные скроллбары вам правильнее делать там же.

Внимание! Вы используете только абсолютное позиционирование - это ваше слабое место!

Вам надо хорошо изучить класс `QLayout`, который является базовым классом менеджеров геометрии https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html

`QWidget::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)` -
этот обработчик событий может быть переопределён в подклассе
для получения событий изменения размера виджета, которые передаются в параметре события.
Когда вызывается `resizeEvent()`, виджет уже имеет новую геометрию.

Т.е. метод `resizeEvent` - это то место где вы должны что-то сделать,
если желаете что-то поменять при изменении размера окна.

Вы не предоставили минимальный модулю `.ui` , который содержит вашу форму,
поэтому я вам продемонстрирую вариант того что вы задумали
на своем минимальном примере.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, uic

qtCreatorFile = "test_3.ui"
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.comboBox.addItems(['Hello','World'])
        self.lineEdit.setText('Hello World')

        self.font = QtGui.QFont()
        self.font.setFamily("Arial")
        self.font.setPointSize(14)        
        self.setFont(self.font)
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        w = self.size().width()
        if  w < 150:
            self.font.setPointSize(8)        
            self.setFont(self.font)
        elif 150 <= w < 300:
            self.font.setPointSize(10)        
            self.setFont(self.font)
        elif 300 <= w < 600:
            self.font.setPointSize(14)        
            self.setFont(self.font)
        elif 600 <= w < 800:
            self.font.setPointSize(24)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 
        elif 800 <= w < 1000:
            self.font.setPointSize(34)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 
        elif 1000 <= w < 1200:
            self.font.setPointSize(44)        
            self.setFont(self.font) 
        elif w >= 1200:
            self.font.setPointSize(54)        
            self.setFont(self.font)             
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**test_3.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>562</width>
    <height>290</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
     <widget class="QScrollArea" name="scrollArea">
      <property name="enabled">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <property name="widgetResizable">
       <bool>true</bool>
      </property>
      <widget class="QWidget" name="scrollAreaWidgetContents">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>0</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>542</width>
         <height>229</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>444</width>
         <height>222</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
            <item>
             <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QComboBox" name="comboBox"/>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
          <item>
           <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
            <item>
             <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
              <property name="orientation">
               <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
              </property>
              <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
               <size>
                <width>40</width>
                <height>20</height>
               </size>
              </property>
             </spacer>
            </item>
            <item>
             <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
              <property name="text">
               <string>PushButton</string>
              </property>
             </widget>
            </item>
           </layout>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>562</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]